# How can I have access to return item in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, roslyn

As we are developing our custom standalone Code Analysis for helping developers to write C# code based on Best practices in VS, we are using Roslyn and its features.

One of our requirements is a little tricky,  we need to parse and compile an methods which have the problem like below concept:

```
var myVariable = SomeExpression...; 
return myVariable;
```

it means that **If** a variable is defined, and then immediately returned and never used again, [GCop][1] should warn to developer and say variable declaration is unnecessary.

```
 protected override void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        NodeToAnalyze = context.Node;

        var varDeclareSyntax = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)NodeToAnalyze;
        if (varDeclareSyntax == null) return;

        var variableDeclare = varDeclareSyntax.ChildNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (variableDeclare == null) return;

        var varDeclarator = variableDeclare.ChildNodes().OfType<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (varDeclarator == null) return;

        var identifierToken = varDeclarator.Identifier.Text;


        var method = varDeclarator.GetSingleAncestor<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();

        var varDeclaratorIndex = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<CSharpSyntaxNode>().IndexOf(varDeclarator);
  /// ??????? TO DO :
```

now we have access to node => (`var item = 10;` )
the question is how we can have access to exactly next line that is 
`return item;`

[image]

I have found the myVariable Syntax node and its value but I dont know how we can find the return **Identider** excatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LocalDeclarationStatement is contained in a larger syntax node, and is a sibling for the `ReturnStatementSyntax.` Your analysis really shouldn't be starting at a LocalDeclarationStatement -- start at the BlockSyntax or something else and then look for both declarations and returns from there.

Another way to try this would be to start finding the ReturnStatementSyntax *first*, and once you see it's a return of a simple variable then you can call SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo() to find the symbol and then go from that symbol to the syntax that defines it. From there you could then see if they are side by side.

Comment: if a methods has multiple returns we should check them, we need to have index if them

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully done ... here is my code

```
 protected override void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
        {
            NodeToAnalyze = context.Node;

        var varDeclareSyntax = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)NodeToAnalyze;
        if (varDeclareSyntax == null) return;

        var variableDeclare = varDeclareSyntax.ChildNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (variableDeclare == null) return;

        var varDeclarator = variableDeclare.ChildNodes().OfType<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (varDeclarator == null) return;

        //var identifierToken = varDeclarator.Identifier.Text; //  <- here we find [item] in ( var item=expression; )

        var method = varDeclarator.GetSingleAncestor<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();

        var varDeclaratorIndex = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<CSharpSyntaxNode>().IndexOf(varDeclarator);

        var allNodes = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<CSharpSyntaxNode>().Select((node, index) => new Node
        {
            Index = index,
            Syntax = node,
            Location = node.GetLocation(),
            Kind = node.Kind(),
            Ancestors = node.Ancestors()
        }).ToArray();

        var maxIndex = allNodes.Where(it => it.Ancestors.Any(x => x == varDeclarator)).Max(it => it.Index.Value);

        if (maxIndex >= allNodes.Length) return;

        var nextReturn = allNodes[maxIndex + 1];

        if (nextReturn.Kind != SyntaxKind.ReturnStatement) return;

        var @return = nextReturn.Syntax as ReturnStatementSyntax;

        if ((@return.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax)?.Identifier.ValueText == varDeclarator.Identifier.ValueText)
        {
            ReportDiagnostic(context, varDeclareSyntax);
        }
    }

    protected override RuleDescription GetDescription()
    {
        return new RuleDescription
        {
            ID = "176",
            Category = Category.Design,
            Message = "Variable declaration is unnecessary due to it used only for return statement"
        };
    }

    private class Node : NodeDefinition
    {
        public IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> Ancestors { get; set; }
        public SyntaxNode Syntax { get; set; }
        public SyntaxKind Kind { get; set; }
    }
```